# Артефакты фильтра SVG в Video при удалении свойства CSS

Tags: css3, html5, svg, видео, filter

Я работаю над расширением браузера, [Night Video Tuner](https://github.com/PyvesB/NightVideoTuner), который внедряет SVG-фильтры в HTML-страницы, используя Javascript, чтобы отфильтровать синий свет из видео.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример того, как будет выглядеть SVG-фильтр, сгенерированный расширением:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="temperature_filter" style="display: none;">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 0.6949030005552019 0 0 0 0 0 0.4310480202110507 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

`style = "display: none;"` используется для предотвращения влияния элемента SVG на разметку страницы.

Я добавляю свойство `filter: url(#tempera_filter)` в атрибут style любого элемента видео, найденного на текущей HTML-странице, чтобы применить этот SVG-фильтр к медиа-контенту.

Вот  https://jsfiddle.net/Pyves/fyy5wrkw/,, демонстрирующая аналогичную настройку, к которой применено видео и его фильтр.

**Проблема**
Пока что этот подход работает только на `Chrome` и `Opera`, в Firefox не работает  из=за [ошибки](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1306960)

Я не могу использовать свойство `style =display: none;` для этого браузера и пытаюсь применить обходные пути, предложенные в  другом вопросе [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926668/inline-html5-svg-filters-without-interfering-with-the-layout).

Я заметил, что общее качество SVG-фильтра значительно ухудшилось в Firefox с появлением визуальных артефактов, особенно в более темных частях видео. Это также тот случай, когда я удаляю style = "display: none;" из фильтра в Opera и Chrome, который предполагает, что это свойство связано с фильтром, который больше не рендерится должным образом. Вот пример, где с левой стороны фильтр без style = "display: none;", а с правой стороны фильтр со свойством, что приводит к гораздо более сильному и плавному фильтру:

Я использую последнюю версию Opera, Firefox и Chrome для Windows, и это происходит независимо от того, включено аппаратное ускорение или нет.

**Вопрос**

- Почему отсутствие стиля = "display: none;" делает рендеринг фильтра
  таким плохим?
- Есть ли обходной путь, чтобы правильно отобразить фильтр в `Firefox`,
  так как `style = display: none;` нельзя использовать с этим в этом
  контексте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/46142733/7394871

Answer (score 3):

SVG фильтры должны использовать цветовое пространство `Linear RGB` по умолчанию. Однако кажется, что `Chrome` жестко привязан к использованию цветового пространства `RGB` при фильтрации элементов `<video>`. Я не уверен почему так происходит. Возможно это `bug`.

Вы можете заставить `Firefox` вести себя так же, как `Chrome`, указав на вашем фильтре:

```
color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
```

К сожалению, Chrome игнорирует это, если вы пытаетесь заставить его использовать цветовое пространство `LinearRGB` (`color-interpolation-filters = "linearRGB"`).

Также вы можете скрыть свой SVG-фильтр на странице, указав нулевую ширину и высоту для элемента .

```html
<video autoplay controls muted src=" https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" style="width: 488px; height: 360px; filter: url(#temperature_filter)">
</video>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <filter id="temperature_filter" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 0.694 0 0 0 0 0 0.431 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fyy5wrkw/8/